# Total angular momentum in Newtonian Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum

In one of MIT's help sessions videos for Newtonian Mechanics with prof W. L. we are asked to prove the following statement:

The total angular momentum relative to a point P is the sum of

1. angular momentum of the COM relative to P, and
2. angular momentum of rotation around COM.

I tried to prove that by using the parallel axis theorem $$I_{total} = I_{CM} + Mr^2 $$
(where $r$ is the distanc of the COM from point P and $M$ is the mass of the object) and saying that $$L_{total} = I_{total}ω = (I_{CM} + Mr^2)ω = I_{CM}ω + Mr^2ω = L_{CM} + L_{P}$$

where $L_{CM}$ is the angular momentum about COM and $L_{P}$ is the angular momentum of the COM about point P. I am not a physics studentst and that was a question asked to freshmen. Is the "proof" above right or wrong? Also is there any other way to prove that statement?

Comment: I is a 3x3 matrix , but $~Mr^2~$ is scalar, thus you are missing something

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the lectures videos it wasn't mentioned anything like that I is a matrix. So we must prove the statement with the simple formulas we already learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is König's theorem. Add the angular momentums of all particles. In a frame $R$:
$$\vec{L}=\sum_im_i\vec{r}_i\times\vec{v}_i$$
Now move to the CoM frame $R^*$:
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{r}_i=\vec{r}^*_i+\vec{r}_e\\
\vec{v}_i=\vec{v}^*_i+\vec{v}_e
\end{cases}$$
yields:
$$\vec{L}
=\sum_im_i\vec{r}^*_i\times\vec{v}^*_i
+\left(\sum_im_i\vec{r}^*_i\right)\times\vec{v}_e
+\vec{r}_e\times\sum_im_i\vec{v}^*_i
+m\vec{r}_e\times\vec{v}_e$$
The two middle terms are zero, the first one is $\vec{L}^*$, the angular momentum of the system in the CoM frame, and the last one is the angular momentum of the CoM in frame $R$ (with $m=\sum_im_i$):
$$\vec{L}=\vec{L}^*+\vec{L}(\text{CoM})$$
which is the result you wanted.

After that, showing that $\vec{L}^*$ can be written as $I\vec{\omega}$ is a different problem. Depending on the situation, $I$ can be a simple number (moment of inertia) or a tensor.

The parallel axis theorem that you tried to use is in fact a consequence of König's theorem.

Comment: Why are the middle terms equal to zero? I don't understand that.

Comment: @LefterisSpanoudakis Just use the definition of the center of mass : $m\vec{OG}=\sum_im_i\vec{OM}_i$ with $O=G$ to understand the second term, and then differentiate this relation with respect to time to understand the third one.